# How to get JSON array value in Swift using Codable

Tags: arrays, json, swift, codable

I'm having trouble getting the direction values from the following JSON:

```
"routeOptions": [
        {
          "name": "Jubilee",
          "directions": [
            "Wembley Park Underground Station",
            "Stanmore Underground Station"
          ],
          "lineIdentifier": {
            "id": "jubilee",
            "name": "Jubilee",
            "uri": "/Line/jubilee",
            "type": "Line",
            "routeType": "Unknown",
            "status": "Unknown"
          }
        }
      ]
```

I believe the directions is a JSON array, which at the moment I'm using Codable as below. I've managed to get the routeOptions name but can't seem to figure out how to get the directions as there's no specific key variable. Please can someone help?

```
struct RouteOptions: Codable {

let name: String?
let directions: [Directions]?

init(name: String, directions: [Directions]) {
    self.name = name
    self.directions = directions
}}

struct Directions: Codable {}
```

Comment: That's invalid JSON - it should always start with a dictionary or array, and as such Codable won't handle it.  Remove the `"routeOptions": ` to make it valid.

Comment: https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser is a great tool for checking your JSON,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle directions as an array of String

```
struct RouteOptions: Codable {
    let name: String
    let directions: [String]
}
```

Here is an example where I fixed the json to be correct

```
let data = """
{ "routeOptions": [
  {
    "name": "Jubilee",
    "directions": [
      "Wembley Park Underground Station",
      "Stanmore Underground Station"
    ],
    "lineIdentifier": {
      "id": "jubilee",
      "name": "Jubilee",
      "uri": "/Line/jubilee",
      "type": "Line",
      "routeType": "Unknown",
      "status": "Unknown"
    }
  }
]}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Root: Decodable {
    let routeOptions: [RouteOptions]
}

struct RouteOptions: Codable {
    let name: String
    let directions: [String]
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result.routeOptions)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```